# Node PhantomJS script onResourceError path issue

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

Having some trouble using the `webpage` API in a phantomJS script I'm using for load testing.

I'm running the script in a child process, like so:

```
var path = require('path');
var childProcess = require('child_process');
var binPath = require('phantomjs').path;

var childArgs = [
  path.join(__dirname, 'phantom-script.js')
];

var spawn = childProcess.spawn;
var child = spawn(binPath, childArgs);

child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
  const buf = Buffer.from(data);
  console.log('stdout:', buf.toString());
});

child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
  const buf = Buffer.from(data);
  console.log('stderr:', buf.toString());
});
```

And my simple phantomJS script:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();


page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) {
  console.log(msg);
};

page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
  console.log(resourceError.errorCode + ':', resourceError.errorString);
};

function runScript() {
  page.open('<webpage-url>', function(status) {
    console.log('Status:', status);
    if (status === 'success') {
      page.evaluate(function() {
        console.log('Title:', document.title);
      });
    }
  });
}

runScript();
```

So to start the phantomJS script, if both of these files are in the `test/` directory, and my current directory is up one from that: `node test/child-process.js`, which then spawns the child process and runs my phantomJS script.

---

So, this gets the script to run, but it always fails in `page.open` because of a resource error. Replacing my url with Google's, or really any website, works fine.

The error logged in `onResourceError` is `stdout: 202: Cannot open file:///Users/<user>/path/to/local/current/directory: Path is a directory`.

This is always the path from which I'm running this script. If I move down a directory into `test/` and run it with `node child-process.js`, the error instead logs that directory.

As a headless browser, I assumed phantomJS would interface with a webpage like any client would, just without rendering the template--what does the current directory from which the script was run have anything to do with opening the webpage? Why would it be trying to load resources from my local directory when the webpage URL points to a public website, hosted at the IP and PORT specified in the first argument of `page.open` (e.g. `xx.xxx.xx.xx:PORT`)?

I'm at a bit of a loss here. The phantomJS path and all that is correct, since it runs the script fine. I just don't understand why `page.open` would attempt to open the directory from which the script was called--what does that have to do with its function, which is to open the URL and load it to the page?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is even worthy of answering--as opposed to just deleting.

I figured it out when I manually typed in the argument `www.google.com`, instead of copy/pasting from the browser, and and I got this as the path in the error: `file:///Users/<user>/path/to/local/current/directory/www.google.com`.

Now I know why I couldn't find a SO question for it. A stupid error on my part at any rate, it would've been a quick debug if the error had appended the IP address and PORT (my "url") to the end of the file path like it did for `www.google.com`, a clear indicator that it's not pinging a URL.

TL;DR: It's a URL, you need `http(s)://`...